# Git: What's the difference between fetching from named remote and fetching from a URL?

Tags: git, fetch

Suppose I clone a git repository from the path `/path/to/repo`. The original repository will be a remote called "origin".  I can fetch objects from the origin with the command `git fetch origin`. This will retrieve all the objects from the remote "origin", including any branches made.

What's curious is that if I explicitly fetch from that same repository with the command `git fetch /path/to/repo`, I appear to retrieve all of the commit objects but not any of the branches.

Why is that?  Am I not doing exactly the same thing in both cases?  How can Git's behavior be so different?

Comment: One usually **pulls** from an URL, rather than *fetching* from URL.

Answer (score 5):

Named remote use their configuration where they setup a `refspec` schema when this remote is fetched:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url   = /path/to/repo
```

So, these two format are equivalent:

```
git fetch origin
git fetch /path/to/repo +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Basically: `git fetch <path> <source>:<destination>`. And the destination is important here because it's where the remote HEAD and branches pointer are stored.

By doing `git fetch /path/to/repo`, you don't set any refspec. As so, it only fetches the commits, not the objects because `git` hasn't been instructed to get and store them.

*There may be some details or naming convention incorrect here, feel free to edit. But the global idea should be correct*

Comment: Note: it doesn't set remote-tracking branches, but it does set `FETCH_HEAD`.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is that fetching from an URL doesn't store state of branches in remote repository into remote-tracking branches (e.g. `refs/heads/master` i.e. `master` branch in remote `origin` into `refs/remotes/origin/master` aka `origin/master`) but only in **`FETCH_HEAD`**.

Using URL instead of setting up remote via `git remote add` is used in *one-off* ***pulls*** i.e.:

```
$ git pull <URL> <branch or tag>
```