# GIT Push to Bare Clarification

Tags: git, version-control

I have 2 non-bare repositories and one bare repositories set up.

After the first repository commits to itself and then pushes to the bare  repository till here everyhing is normal.

Then in the second repository I clone the bare repo and I get the contents into the second repo.

Then in the second repo I add a new file and commit to itself still I have not pused into bare repo.

Then I do a git status and I get the message like "Your branch is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit" : So this is natural behaviour since I have not pushed into bare repo yet.

And later i push into the bare repo and cd to the bare repo and do a **git log** and I see the latest commit is successful.

Then I return back to the second repo and do a **git status** and still I'm getting the message "Your branch is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit".

Why am I still getting the same message even after the bare repo has the latest commit.

```
**EDIT**:And if I try to pull or fetch the message still remains.
1) user@ubuntu:~/user2$ git pull /home/user/central [/home/user/central-Bare repo]

2) user@ubuntu:~/user2$ git fetch /home/user/central
From /home/user/central
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD [And this fetch command has no output why does this happen.Am I fetching correctly]
```

And when i do a diff b/w the master and the origin/master I get the foll:

```
user@ubuntu:~/user2$ git diff master origin/master
diff --git a/anotherfile.txt b/anotherfile.txt
deleted file mode 100644
index 6acd600..0000000
--- a/anotherfile.txt
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,2 +0,0 @@
-This is a second file to be committed
-hello
```

I have added a few files to user2 repo and the git log for user2 which is a non-bare repo and the git log for the bare repo is the same .
The git status for user2 repo is as shown:

```
user@ubuntu:~/user2$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

And the result of git branch -vva result in the non-bare repo user2 is as shown:

```
user@ubuntu:~/user2$ git branch -vva
* master                dac4ae0 [origin/master: ahead 4] Fifth Commit
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master 8cfb52f Initial Commit
```

Comment: I tried by myself it is ok. Could you provide a full example?

Comment: I have given all steps here.What else do I need to provide?

Comment: I followed your all steps, it's ok. So I think maybe some command you use wrong. Btw, Can you show `git branch -vva` result?

Comment: I have added the result of git branch -vva result in the question

Comment: From the result of `git branch -vva`, your origin/master is not updated. You can check the origin url with `git remote -v`. Also I want to know the exactly command you used to push.

Comment: I tried thr git remove -v and it returns /home/user/central as the result and this is my bare repo. The command I use to push from a non-bare to a bare repo is : git push /home/user/central

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I catch the problem.
First you need see this question.

[Git: What's the difference between fetching from named remote and fetching from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085504/git-whats-the-difference-between-fetching-from-named-remote-and-fetching-from/14090822#14090822)

Then I suggest you do the following command in the second rep:

```
git remote add origin <bare repo path>
git pull origin
git push
```

Or when you init second repo use `git clone <bare repo path>`.

Comment: :Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The message "Your branch is ahead of `origin/master` by 1 commit" means that your local master has one commit that your remote master reference (`origin/master`) doesn't have. Maybe updating it with `git fetch` resolve your problem.

Comment: I have edited the question as per your suggestion and still nothing happens and the message still displays

Comment: What is the return of the following command `git diff master origin/master`?

Comment: I have added the result of git diff master origin/master to the question

Comment: Try to to perform a `git log`. The last commit in your local repository is the same in your bare repository?

Comment: Yes it is.I performed git log on both the bare and the non-bare repo I get the same output.That's what is confusing me.

Comment: The command `git remote show origin` shows your bare repository?

Comment: Can you post the `git status` result?

Comment: I have added the git status result in the question