# git local repo is always ahead of remote, even after fetch, and diff with remote shows a delta

Tags: git

Looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432579/git-your-branch-is-ahead-by-x-commits), but still baffled.

I did a `git pull` of a branch, followed it by a `git fetch`.

I still get a message saying my repo is ahead by X commits, and `git diff origin/branch`, which, to my understanding, compares my local code with a remote branch, shows a delta.

This is after I pulled and fetched, and looking at my code shows that the reported diffs don't actually exist.  My code and the upstream code are identical.

I also tried rebasing based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052788/git-says-local-branch-is-ahead-of-remote-after-having-pulled-from-remote), to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085504/git-whats-the-difference-between-fetching-from-named-remote-and-fetching-from) whether it is helpful.

Comment: Just FYI: `git pull` is the same as `git fetch` followed by a merge. So doing a `git fetch` directly after a `git pull` is guaranteed to do nothing.

Comment: @pktangyue - do you mean that if I want my local repo to actually be synced, I need to include those extra parameters every time?  I'm still puzzling out what they mean, though that may be because I'm fairly new to git.  At any rate, I can't believe that something as basic as keeping my local repo up to date is so involved, and is beyond a simple command?

Comment: @pktangyue - you, that did it, seems to have sorted itself out now.  But there must be a simpler way?

Comment: Did you ever push? Of course you are ahead if you don't push your changes.

Comment: @iltempo - yeah, I pushed, in fact, the delta was exactly the two commits a colleague made since I pushed.  Somehow it was claiming that someone else's commits were making my repo ahead of the upstream repo, which is where I got those changes to begin with...

Comment: @MrSilverSnorkel did you add any parameters when using `git push` or `git fetch`.

Comment: You say you did `git pull` "of a branch".  Which branch?  It sounds like your tracking branch is `origin/branch` but you're not pulling that branch?

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier...initially, when pulling and fetching, I just pulled/fetched the branch, so `git pull origin branch` etc.  Later, I tried this with a refspec parameter and the problem went away.  Since then, git pull has been working as I would expect it, despite numerous pulls, pushes, and so on.  Perhaps my local repository's meta data was somehow not updated, and pulling the refspec helped?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have commits in your branch you want to keep? Or are you just trying to make your master branch up to date?

Either way:

```
git stash
git branch master.tmp # or whatever name you want - this saves any changes
git checkout master.tmp
git pull origin master
git branch -D master
git checkout master --force
git stash pop
```

This will cause you to have two branches: The master (up to date) and your current one (`master.tmp`)